# Find JQuery/AngularJS added data to an element with Capybara

Tags: jquery, angularjs, capybara, poltergeist

I need to test a web page, where jQuery/AngularJS adds some data to the attributes of an element, in this case 'value', which is not visible to the default selector. I am using Capybara with Poltergeist. I would like to verify the element value but the standard way fails:

```
expect(find(:xpath, "//input[@type='text']").value).to eq('3')
```

OR

```
find("//input[@type='text']/@value='3'")
```

The element looks like this (the value appears in the Properties):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="link.days_until_expiration" placeholder="Never" maxlength="4" ng-change="passPositiveNumbers(link);" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

In Chrome console I was able to select it with

```
$('input[type="text"]').data('value', '3')
```

but there is not data method in Capybara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS will affect the value property rather than the value attribute, which means you can't query for it using xpath (you can only query for value attributes that are there at page load/parse time) - if it is the only input with 'Never' as placeholder/id/name/label, or you can use parent element to scope it so it is the only matching input, then the following should work (replace page with a found parent element if scoping is needed)

```
expect(page).to have_field('Never', with: '3')
```